# Setting textfield text does not work

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Beginner programmer trying to understand why I cannot accomplish this simple task. I know it is most likely a very simple solution but hoping that someone will explain the WHY.

I have a screen where users can input emails into a textfield. The idea is that if upon entering the e-mail, if it is not already in the stored emails, it will prompt the user to enter the new email/contact into the store. Since I check if the e-mail is valid BEFORE popping up the screen for contact creation, I'd like to take the text entered and put it directly into the "Email" field on the new contact creation page and not allow editing. I've tried numerous methods but CANNOT get the email to show up in the text field. Can someone explain why this is?

Code from initial VC where users enter their emails. If the email does not exist in the store, this code creating the contact creator page is fired:

```
//I created this custom initializer since setting the text field (as I did below) would not work
ContactCreationViewController *contactCreationVC = [[ContactCreationViewController alloc] initWithEmail:trimmedText];
contactCreationVC.delegate = self;

//initially I tried setting the text here but it did not work, I now understand why
//[contactCreationVC.emailField setText:@"asdsadasd"];

[contactCreationVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[contactCreationVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];

[self presentViewController:contactCreationVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is the code for the actual ContactCreatorVC:

```
-(instancetype) initWithEmail:(NSString*)email{
    self = [super init];

    //tried setting email here which works as I check with breakpoints
    [self setEmail:email];

    //self.email = email here when I check
    return self;
}

....

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
switch (indexPath.row) {

....

    case 3: {
        ContactCreationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:contactCreationCellIdentifier];
        cell.titleLabel.text = @"E-Mail";
        cell.userEntryTextfield.tag = 3;
        cell.userEntryTextfield.delegate = self;
        cell.userEntryTextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;

//I try setting the email here but self.email = nil (don't understand why)
        cell.userEntryTextfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.email];
        cell.userEntryTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.userEntryTextfield.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        self.emailField = cell.userEntryTextfield;
        return cell;
    }

.....

}
```

I feel stupid for even asking such a simple question but I clearly am not understanding what is going on behind the scenes cause I've tried everything. Can anyone explain what is going on and suggest the ideal solution from a best practice standpoint?

EDIT: I guess my question could be more concise...it basically boils down to: why when I set self.email in the init does it not stick when I access self.email in the cellForRow method (it becomes nil)?

(the textfield is in a cell in a tableview)

Comment: In your `init` you do `[self setEmail:self.email]`, but at that point `self.email` is still `nil`. You should rather pass the argument from the init method - `[self setEmail:email];`

Comment: @Losiowaty yes, sorry you are right. That was a typo, I set it to the argument and it still doesn't work. I've edited my question to reflect this, thanks.

Comment: Ok :) now - how did you declare your email property? And did you actually override its setter?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *email; I did not override the setter, is that something I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
[contactCreationVC.emailField setText:@"asdsadasd"];
```

You have only just created `contactCreationVC`. Its view has not loaded, so `emailField` is `nil` (easily demonstrated by some rudimentary logging). A message to `nil` does nothing.

The correct approach is: never touch another view controller's outlets. Set a *property* of the other view controller and let *it* deal with its own outlets. In this case, the other view controller would need to use the property to set the `emailField` `text` in its `viewDidLoad`.

As to why *that* approach doesn't work for you, there isn't enough info to answer it as far as I can tell. If you can prove that things go in this order:

1. A ContactCreatorVC `init` is called with an actual email value, and the property is set.
2. The property has a strong (retain) policy so the value is retained.
3. The very same ContactCreatorVC instance now has its `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called, and that moment the property is `nil`.

If you can prove all that, then the only logical conclusion is that meanwhile some other code has come along and set the property to `nil`.

Comment: Yeah I gathered that, thank you for the explanation. That was attempt one but my problem now is why the other attempt I try also doesn't set it correctly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I'm looking right at your code. That line is there and that line is wrong. If that's not your real code, show your real code. Show all and only the actual code that the question is about.

Comment: I meant that it was my FIRST attempt at setting the textfield which did not work and I left it there because I wanted an explanation, which you provided, and I appreciate. I showed my second attempt to set it in the code snippet just below that and that did not work either which is why I am still confused. As you said since a message to nil does nothing I left it in to get the explanation.

Comment: The line is still there. If it isn't part of the question, remove it. Clarify your question to be only about the lines of code the problem is about.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I thought you wanted to know why that line didn't work, and I explained it.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you taking the time regardless. I guess my question could be more concise...it basically boils down to: why when I set self.email in the init does it not stick when I access self.email in the cellForRow method (it becomes nil)?

Comment: Good question, but there isn't enough info to answer it as far as I can tell. If you can prove that things go in this order: (1) a ContactCreatorVC `init` is called with an actual email value, and the property is set; (2) the property has a strong (retain) policy so the value is retained; (3) the very same ContactCreatorVC instance now has its `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called, and that moment the property is `nil` - if you can prove all that, then the only logical conclusion is that meanwhile some other code has come along and set the property to `nil`.

Comment: ...and you are the man Matt. It took an experienced programmer to go through things with me for me to realize what a stupid error I made. (2) is where I messed up...an error I won't make again. Thank you!!!  

++ for solving it without me including that code

Comment: By the way, this has nothing at all to do with your question, but your use of `stringWithFormat` is wrong. Just set the text to the string, plain and simple.

Comment: yeah I normally do it that way I was just trying everything I could to make it work

Comment: I'll add that little sequence to my answer so things are closer to what you needed.